# Add axis name into chart c#

Tags: c#, charts, axis

I'm working with *winforms* using C#.

I use chart and I want to set the titles of the X- and Y-axis in code. I tried

```
chart1.chartarea(0).axisX.title = "xxx"
```

but it does't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Could you plz add more code

Comment: Except for all those many typos your code is correct and works. Here is the version without typos: `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "xxx";`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am using the charts control on the web and setting the X and Y axis titles are done in the following way.

I assume the API would be the same for winforms.

```
var chartArea = new ChartArea("MyChart");
...
chartArea.AxisX.Title = "xxx";
chartArea.AxisY.Title = "yyy";
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions worked for me. I used the following code which helped me to add Axis title on windows form chart. I am adding a couple of useful properties so anyone who is working on it can have an idea how to use it. I searched a lot to find out all those properties. There are very few examples of this types.

```
chartESTOr.Titles.Add("Est OR Date " + " (" + Year + ")").Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold); // Chart Title
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Month";  // Chart X Axis Title
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Center; // Chart X axis Text Alignment 
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Rotated270; // Chart X Axis Text Orientation 
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold); // Chart X axis Title Font
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1; // Chart X Axis Interval
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Quote Value (USD)"; // Chart Y Axis Title 
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;  // Chart Y axis Text Alignment 
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal; // Chart Y Axis Text Orientation
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold); // Chart Y axis Title Font
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:0,}K"; // Chart Y Axis lable format
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @TaW in comments this code works as: `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "xxx";`

for dynamic addition the code by @Mytroy2050 is what works