# label x and y axis chart c#

Tags: c#, charts, axis

I`m having trouble on putting labels on x and y axis on my chart.

I found a solution to this link:
[Add axis name into chart c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589905/add-axis-name-into-chart-c-sharp)

I already added `using System.Windows.DataVisualization.Charting;` 
but whenever i type the ".AxisX" the only things that it suggest are "AxisScrollBarClicked", "AxisViewChanged", "AxisViewChanging", and "AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o00mc.png)

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Look again! Then you'll that the axes belong to a chart's Chartarea!

Answer (score 0):

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "xxx";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "xxx";
```

it was suggested by @TaW from the link [Add axis name into chart c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589905/add-axis-name-into-chart-c-sharp)